# Magento 1.9.1 - save products very slow

Tags: magento, backend, reindex

Recently when we tried to update a product's attribute on magento backend, it took around 90 seconds to save. I know maybe there is some re-index problem. However; when I tested on our staging site (identical Amazon EC2 server and I also duplicated the database from RDS and run another rds to make them basically identical.) 
The strange thing is on our staging, when we tried to update a product attribute, it only took us around 10 seconds instead of 90 seconds.

Anybody has any thought about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You try by changing `index mode` of `Category Products`,`Catalog URL Rewrites` and `Product Prices` to `Manual Update` instead of `Update on Save`